# How can I assign a value to an int variable with optional?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

For example, I have got a code like this:

```
class Point
{
    private String x;
    private String y;

    public String getX () { //Here can not use Optional<String>
        return this.x;
    }

    public String getY () {
        return this.y;
    }

    public Point(String x, String y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

...

```
    Point point = new Point(null, "14.2");

    if(ofNullable(point.getX().isPresent()) {
      this.xCoordinate = point.getX();
    }

    if(ofNullable(point.getY().isPresent()) {
      this.yCoordinate = point.getY();
    }
```

I want to do it in a cleaner way, something like this:

```
this.x = ofNullable(point.getX()).ifPresent((x) -> x)
```

I know this is not working but I tried almost everything but I can not get it to work.

Comment: `ofNullable(point.getY().isPresent()` is a bit confusing. Is `getY()` returning an optional? Or are you creating an optional on `point`?

Comment: The brackets here don't match up correctly.

Comment: @ernest_k I edited the code. Is it possible with these conditions?

Comment: You can use `ofNullable(point.getX()).ifPresent(x -> this.x = x);` but this is not cleaner than an idiomatic `if(point.getX() != null) this.x = point.getX();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Integer` instead of the primitive type `int`

You didn't post enough code, but your `getX` method definition should be:

`Optional<Integer> getX()` instead of `int getX()`.

If you can't modify the class with the method, create a wrapper class or something. Without seeing all the code, I can't say much more...

EDIT:

Make your point class store optional values:

```
class Point
{
    private Optional<String> x;
    private Optional<String> y;

    public Optional<String> getX () { //Here can not use Optional<String>
        return this.x;
    }

    public Optional<String> getY () {
        return this.y;
    }

    public Point(String x, String y) {
        this.x = ofNullable(x);
        this.y = ofNullable(y);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Point point = new Point(null, "14.2");

if(point.getX().isPresent()) {
  this.xCoordinate = point.getX();
}

if(point.getY().isPresent()) {
  this.yCoordinate = point.getY();
}
```

Comment: I extended the code, I hope now it is clear what I want.

Comment: I commented there I do not want to make them Optional.